# Error in texi2dvi running knitr::knit2pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr

If I run

```
knit2pdf("test.Rnw")
```

...on a .Rnw file using `knitr` in R, I get this error:

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'test.tex' failed.
```

Anyone know how I can resolve?

Comment: Try compliling the `test.tex` file yourself. I guess the error-massage  of your Latex compiler will be more helpful.

Comment: No didn't get resolved

Comment: @luciano I'm also trying this from a different angle, but not successfully yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731493/texi2dvi-error-when-running-a-rnw-script-with-launchcontrol

Comment: Reading the example,   @Nancy was successfull in the end

Comment: Ensure `LaTeX` is installed. If not, download and install a distribution like `TeX Live` or `MiKTeX`. Run `Sys.which("pdflatex")` in R. It should return the path to the pdflatex executable. If not, set the path manually in R or your system's environment variables. Update knitr and related packages. Use `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` to ensure you have the latest versions.

Comment: You should clean temp files. Use `clean = TRUE` in `knit2pdf`. This automatically deletes intermediate files that might cause conflicts. Try `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. This installs a lightweight LaTeX distribution specifically for R.