# texi2dvi() error when running a .Rnw script with LaunchControl

Tags: r, knitr, launchd

I'm trying to compile a knitr script on a timer using [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) (a launchd GUI for scheduling cron-like jobs on OSX).

I have a dispatcher.R script that does this:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Rscript
library("knitr")
setwd("~/somedirectory")
knit2pdf("my_script.Rnw", output= "my_script.tex")
```

When I run it interactively from in RStudio, my_script.Rnw works great. I get the desired PDF output. However, when launchd runs the dispatcher.R script I get this error:

> Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
>     Running 'texi2dvi' on 'my_script.tex' failed.
>   Execution halted

The .tex file gets generated, but then it doesn't compile. I a would say it was problem with my LaTeX installation path, but since it works using `knit2pdf()` I'm not sure. What could be the issue?

---

Still working on this. Updates:

- No .log file gets produced with `knit2pdf()` via LaunchControl, but I get a .tex file and /figure folder.
- I updated MacTex and also tried a minimal example of an empty document and I got the same error about texi2dvi.
- When I run `knit2pdf("my_script.Rnw", output = "my_script.tex")` using LaunchControl and *then* go back to RStudio and run `texi2dvi("my_script.tex", pdf = TRUE)`, then I get the desired outcome.
- The problem reproduces on Sierra and Yosemite
- On Sierra there is an additional error about `In my_script_latex_pkg("framed", system.file("misc", "framed.sty", package = "knitr")) :  unable to find LaTeX package 'framed'; will use a copy from knitr`
- I tried `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))` and it didn't help.
- Running `$ Rscript dispatcher.R` from the command line works just fine. The PDF compiles.
- Running a bash script with `Rscript dispatcher.R`in LaunchControl does *not* work; same error about texi2dvi.

Comment: Can you do a diff on the intermediate `.tex` files produced by the two different methods? If you call `texi2dvi` directly does it work on a minimal `.tex` file?

Comment: I ran it both ways and saved the .tex files as two differently-name txt files. $ diff file1.txt file2.txt showed no differences.

Comment: Is there a potentially relevant warning that you're not seeing due to your `suppressWarnings`? What about calling `texi2dvi` directly on that file or on a minimal example? And is a `.log` file produced?

Comment: I just ran it using only ```texi2dvi``` and did get control sequence errors. ```The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
! Undefined control sequence.```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a .Rnw file using LaunchControl for task scheduling, create the following files in the same directory. Then, run the *.sh script in the scheduler. Voila! The problem I was encountering in my original post was the LaunchControl doesn't (by default, at least) read ~/.bash_profile, so adding the PATH variable into the .sh script resolves this.

## 1) Your *.Rnw script

This is any `knitr` script that you can compile without issue from RStudio.

## 2) A *.R script

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Rscript
library("knitr")
setwd("~/some_directory")
knit2pdf("yourscript.Rnw", output = "yourscript.tex")
```

## 3) A *.sh script

Make sure that you have the PATH variable to your LaTeX installation.

```
#! /bin/bash 

PATH="/usr/texbin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Rscript yourscript_dispatcher.R
```

This solution works on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 on R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31).